# Ideal $I=\langle a,b,c,d \rangle \subseteq R$ with $uI \subseteq \langle a,b \rangle$ and $vI \subseteq \langle c,d \rangle$, for some $u,v \in R$

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative integral domain, which is a $k$-algebra, $k$ is a field of characteristic zero.
Let $a,b,c,d \in R$.

Assume that the following three conditions are satisfied:

**(i)** $I= \langle a,b,c,d \rangle = \langle a+b, c+d \rangle$.

**(ii)** There exist $u \in R$ such that $uI \subseteq \langle a,b \rangle$.

**(iii)** There exist $v \in R$ such that $vI \subseteq \langle c,d \rangle$.

> Is it true that $I=\langle a,b \rangle =\langle c,d \rangle$?
> If not, is there an additional condition that would guarantee $I=\langle a,b \rangle =\langle c,d \rangle$?

I have tried to play with the three conditions, but have not got something interesting about such ideal.
For example:
$a=\alpha(a+b)+\beta(c+d)$, $b=\gamma(a+b)+\delta(c+d)$, $va=Pc+Qd$, $vb=Sc+Td$, etc.

Any hints and comments are welcome!

Comment: Easy counterexamples, e.g. $\,a\neq 0,\ b,c,d=0\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque, thank you for the counterexamples. (I should have required $abcd \neq 0$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that conditions **(ii)** and **(iii)** are not constraining since they are automatically satisfied for any $u,v$ with $u\in (a,b)$ and $v\in (c,d)$.

Hence those two conditions are irrelevant and can be ignored.

To show that condition **(i)** doesn't imply $I=(a,b)=(c,d)$, choose $a,c$ such that $(a)\ne (c)$ and let $b=a$ and $d=c$.

Then 
$$I=(a,b,c,d)=(a,c)=(2a,2c)=(a+b,c+d)$$
but 
$$(a,b)=(a)\ne (c)=(c,d)$$

Comment: Thank you very much, especially for pointing out that conditions (ii) and (iii) are not constraining. What if we further assume that $a \neq b$ and $c \neq d$? I guess there are still counterexamples. I wonder if there is a mild condition that guarantees $(a,b)=(c,d)$.

Comment: Perhaps the following is another counterexample: $R=k[x,y]$, $a=x+x^2+y^2$, $b=-2xy$, $c=x^2+y^2$, $d=y-2xy$. Here $(a,b,c,d)=(a+b,c+d)=(x+(x-y)^2,y+(x-y)^2)=(x,y)$, but probably $(a,b) \neq (c,d)$.